# Not able to write to file

Tags: python, file

I am trying to make a string write in a text file, but only if that string is already not in the text file.

```
b = raw_input("IP Adress: ")
os.system('cls')
if(b == '0'):
    a = 0
c = raw_input("Player Name: ")
if(c == '0'):
    a = 0
if(a != 0):
    line = "Text\IPs\{}.txt".format(b)
    output_filee = open(line, 'w+')
    output_file = open(line, 'r')
    lines = output_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if(line != c):
            found = 1
    if(found == 1):
        output_filee.write(c)
    output_file.close()
    output_filee.close()
    print '"{}" has been added to the IP Address {}'.format(c,b)
```

The code above makes the new file in the folder, but with nothing in it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The "found" variable is already defined before-hand.

Comment: The logic in your loop is wrong. It will set `found = 1` if there's any line that is different from `c`, even if `c` matches some other line.

Comment: There are a lot of logic mistakes in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your `for` loop is wrong. It's not checking whether the string is missing from the file, it's checking whether there's some line in the file that doesn't match the string. If the file is empty, the loop won't do anything, so it never sets `found = 1`.

You need to invert the logic. Change it to:

```
found = False
for line in lines:
    if line == c:
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    output_filee.write(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the flawed logic mentioned in [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38131833/1925388), there are a few more problems:

- With the current setting, the new file will only contain the new player name, whereas what I think you want is the new file to contain all the previous names as well.
- `if(line != c)` will always be `false`, as `line` will always have an `\n` at the end.

So, I think you want this:

```
import os


b = raw_input("IP Adress: ")
a = 1

if(b == '0'):
    a = 0
c = raw_input("Player Name: ")
if(c == '0'):
    a = 0

if(a != 0):
    filepath = "{}.txt".format(b)

    found = False
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        output_file = open(filepath, 'r')
        lines = output_file.readlines()
        output_file.close()
        for line in lines:
            if line.rstrip() == c:
                found = True
                print '"{}" already present\n'.format(c)
                break

    if not found:
        output_filee = open(filepath, 'a')
        output_filee.write(c + '\n')
        output_filee.close()
        print '"{}" has been added to the IP Address {}'.format(c, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I have noticed with your snippet.

First of all, you are using the `os` module, but it isn't imported.

Second, are you wanting this to only work on windows? Because os.system calls are at best 'meh', until you want to be cross platform and then they are almost worthless. So, if that isn't a problem, then ignore that part.

Where is `a` defined at? You only define it if some conditions aren't met. My suggestion to avoid errors, is to set a to some arbitrary initial state and that will prevent undefined errors from happening.

Also, your snippet is fairly hard to follow syntactically. As you write more code, or come back to old code, this makes maintenance very difficult.

Consider something like this for reference:

```
import os
a = ""
b = raw_input("IP Adress: ")
found = False

os.system('cls')

if(b == '0'):
    a = 0

c = raw_input("Player Name: ")

if(c == '0'):
    a = 0

if(a != 0):
    try:
        f = "Text/IPs/{}.txt".format(b)
        with open(f, "w+") as myfile:
            for line in myfile.read():
                if(line == c):
                    found = True

            if found == False:
                myfile.write(c)
                print '"{}" has been added to the IP Address {}'.format(c,b)

    except Exception, e:
        print(str(e))
```

You can consolidate your read / write into a single loop. There are some other things that I would normally do to tidy this up but I only had a few minutes to post this. Hope this gets you pointed in the write direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this one:

```
def add(filename, text):
    text += '\n'
    with open(filename, 'a+') as lines:
    if not any(text==l for l in lines):
        lines.write(text)

ip_adress = raw_input("IP Adress: ")
name = raw_input("Player Name: ")
if ip_adress != '0' and name != '0':
    add(r"Text\IPs\{}.txt".format(ip_adress), name)
```